# Error with curve( ): 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

Tags: r, function, vector, curve

I have a function that has a vector in the numerator and the sum of the vector in the denominator.  So each component is one component of the vector divided by a function that depends on the sum of the components.  I want to plot a curve representing the function in the first component holding fixed the other components.  Why doesn't this code work?

```
y <- vector(length=2)
y0 <- c(1,2)
f <- function(y) y/(1+sum(y))
g <- function(x) f(c(x,y0[2]))[1]
curve(g, 0, 2)
```

Both f and g evaluate as expected at numerical values, but the curve function gives the error:

```
Error in curve(g, 0, 2) : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

I tried Vectorizing g with no success.  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 9):

You could try:

```
h <- Vectorize(g); curve(h, 0, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks!  I tried curve(Vectorize(g), 0, 2), which didn't work.  Any idea why?

Comment: From `?curve`: The way curve handles expr has caused confusion. It first looks to see if expr is a name (also known as a symbol), in which case it is taken to be the name of a function, and expr is replaced by a call to expr with a single argument with name given by xname. Otherwise it checks that expr is either a call or an expression, and that it contains a reference to the variable given by xname (using all.vars): anything else is an error.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré : Thanks for the quote from the manual. It does not explain though why  `Vectorize()` is necessary. Probably because `curve()` invokes its `expr` argument by passing to it a vector of all abscissa points _at once_; but I am just guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

`curve()` uses an expr that is expected to be vectorized, so it can pass in `n` points all at once as `x`.

Observe `f(1:10)` gives a vector of length 10, while `g(1:10)` only gives a single value, which `curve()` does not like. A simple fix is to vectorize the function, ex.

```
curve(Vectorize(g)(x), 0, 2)
```

where `'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'`. `curve(Vectorize(g), 0, 2)` won't work because `Vectorize(g)` needs to be evaluated with `x` first.